# Graphql Apollo Server + Vue => Image Upload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, graphql, apollo

Im using Vue with vue-apollo in the frontend and graphql stand-alone Apollo Server 2 with mongodb through mongoose in the backend. I have a simple blog application in which posts also have an Image. Everything works fine except uploading Images. I want the images to be uploaded to my local filesystem in a folder on my backend and only the path to the image saved in my mongodb document.

the mutation:

```
 async createPost(parent, args, context, info) {
         //...
        const {stream, filename} = await args.img

        const img_path = await upload({stream, filename})

        const post = await Post.save({
            //img is a string in my mongo model
            img: img_path,
            author_name: args.user.username,
            author_email: args.user.email
        });
    }
```

the upload method that should return the path and save the image to local:

```
const upload = ({ stream, filename }) => {
  const id = shortid.generate()
  const path = `${UPLOAD_DIR}/${filename}-${id}`
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  stream
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename))
  .on("finish", () => resolve(path))
  .on("error", reject(Error))
);
}
```

The error im getting is that stream and filename are undefined when calling upload() but args.img is an object if i log it. And uploading them to my local folder doesnt work neither. Any help is appreciated and marked as accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to share your graphql Schema so that we can see the types you're returning. However, Here's how i have been handling file uploads in most of my apps.

### graphql-schema

```
type File {
    id: ID!
    filename: String!
    mimetype: String!
    path: String!
  }
```

### mongoose schema

```js
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";
const fileSchema = new Schema({
  filename: String,
  mimetype: String,
  path: String,
});
export default model("File", fileSchema);
```

### Function to store uploads:

```js
const storeUpload = async ({ stream, filename, mimetype }) => {
  const id = shortid.generate();
  const path = `images/${id}-${filename}`;
  // (createWriteStream) writes our file to the images directory
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    stream
      .pipe(createWriteStream(path))
      .on("finish", () => resolve({ id, path, filename, mimetype }))
      .on("error", reject)
  );
};
```

### To process the uploads

```js
const processUpload = async (upload) => {
  const { createReadStream, filename, mimetype } = await upload;
  const stream = createReadStream();
  const file = await storeUpload({ stream, filename, mimetype });
  return file;
};
```

### Mutation

```js
export default {
  Mutation: {
    uploadFile: async (_, { file }) => {
      mkdir("images", { recursive: true }, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
      const upload = await processUpload(file);
      // save our file to the mongodb
      await File.create(upload);
      return upload;
    },
  },
};
```

[Here you can find an article i wrote on how to handle file uploads](https://dev.to/dnature/handling-file-uploads-with-apollo-server-2-0-14n7)